# How to assign array of record to other variable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

In the below code I get strange (or not) results for `OldRecord[0].Value` after I assign `NewRecord := OldRecord;` it seems that both `OldRecord[0].Value` and `NewRecord[0].Value` are set to `new`.

```
type
  TMyRec = array of record
    Name: string;
    Value: Variant; 
    // more fields
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  OldRecord, NewRecord: TMyRec;
begin
  SetLength(OldRecord, 1);
  OldRecord[0].Name := 'Test';
  OldRecord[0].Value := 'old';

  ShowMessage(OldRecord[0].Value); // old

  // SetLength(OldRecord, 1);
  NewRecord := OldRecord;
  NewRecord[0].Value := 'new';

  ShowMessage(OldRecord[0].Value); // new
  ShowMessage(NewRecord[0].Value); // new
end;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: In short dyn arrays are reference types. Both references refer to the same object. To make a copy use `NewArray := Copy(OldArray)`

Comment: Thank you @David! can you make an answer?

Comment: No. It's a duplicate. Read the answers at the dupe question.

Comment: You did not mentioned `Copy` in the duplicate. in any case thanks again. I was totally unaware of this.